# Omron PLC Ethernet card

Tags: plc

I have an Ethernet card in a Omron PLC. Is there any way to do an automatic check to see if the Ethernet card is working? If not, is there a manual way? For example, if the card was to go out on the PLC it would give an error. But if the card just loses signal with the server then it would NOT give error. Any help on how to do this?

Comment: Which model of ethernet unit is it?  Which Omron PLC?  An ethernet/IP unit (for PC<->PLC communication) or is it for motor control?

Comment: I am going off memory but its a CJ1M , PC to PLC , Ethernet Unit Omron CJ1W-ETN21

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several types of errors you can check for.  The way you do this depends on the type of error. Things you can check :

ETN unit Error Status (found at PLC CIO address CIO 1500 + (25 x unit number) +18)

What it reports :  IP configuration, routing, DNS, mail, network services, etc, errors.
See : Manual Section 8-2

The ETN unit also keeps an internal error log (manual section 8-3) that you can read out to your HMI software (if you use it) using FINS commands.  This documents all manner of errors internal to the ETN unit.

There are also other memory reservations in the PLC for CPU bus devices (like the ETN unit) which provide basic status flags you can include in ladder logic to raise alarms, etc.  (See section 4-3 : Auxiliary Area Data).

These flags indicate whether the unit is initializing, for example, has initialized successfully, is ready to execute network commands, whether the last executed command completed OK or returned an error code (which can be read from the Error Log as above), etc.  These can indicate whether the PLC is unable to properly communicate with the ETN device.

Comment: thanks i will look into these, it sounds like the best option is to use the Has Initialized successfully bit.

Comment: @GlenMorse I would say that many (if not most) of the error-checking diagnostic tools are important.  Errors can happen after a successful initialization.  Best practice is to check all potentially relevant status information - that way when something goes wrong you can raise a very specific alarm.  This helps troubleshooting and downtime immensely.  There's nothing worse than a mystery problem and when you end up with a mystery problem you end up adding in the error checking reactively anyway to try to hunt down the root cause.

Comment: Great answer sorry it took me so long to approve. Was out of town and busy. But that's alot !

Answer (score 1):

You can implement single byte location which will be autoincremented each second by the server. Then every few seconds you check in your PLC logic if old reading is the same as new reading, and if it is then you trigger an alarm that physical server (which is an communication client) is not communicating to PLC ethernet card.

Comment: Great idea. Would doing this every second by the server put a strain on the server?

Comment: @avra - it sounds like he is does not want to check for communication faults between PLC<->Client, it sounds like he wants an internal diagnostic tool which will verify that the ethernet unit itself is functioning independently of any external devices.  For example, if someone cut the ethernet cable your check above would flag an alarm, even though the problem is a broken cable and not a broken ethernet unit.

Comment: Exactly,  Currently i have a sever going to a panel/computer. so i figured i would use the panel to send the data, but in the case above, if a cord was cut it would not help.  :(  So yes do you know of a internal diagnostic tool?